# Is the cohomology $H^1(X, \mathcal{E}^\nabla)$ trivial, for the sheaf of constants of an algebraic connection $\nabla$?

Tags: schemes, sheaf-cohomology, connections, kahler-differentials, differentials

Suppose that $\pi:X\to S$ is a flat morphism between Noetherian, integral schemes (of characteristic zero, if need be).
Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$, and
$$\nabla:\mathcal{E} \to \Omega_{X/S}\otimes\mathcal{E}$$
an $\mathcal{O}_S$-linear connection.

It would also be very useful to me if we allow $\nabla$ to be a logarithmic connection, i.e. taking values in $\Omega_{X/S}(D)\otimes\mathcal{E}$ for some divisor $D \subset X$.

We have the sheaf of $\nabla$-constants, a sub-$\mathcal{O}_S$ module of $\mathcal{E}$:
$$\mathcal{E}^\nabla := \mathrm{ker}\left[\mathcal{E} \xrightarrow{\nabla} \Omega_{X/S}\otimes\mathcal{E}\right]$$

**Question**:
What is the sheaf cohomology $H^1(X,\mathcal{E}^\nabla$)? (or rather the higher direct image $R^1\pi_*(\mathcal{E}^\nabla))$

If $\mathcal{E}^\nabla$ is a constant sheaf, then it is flasque and hence acyclic. However I haven't been able to figure out how to show that $\mathcal{E}^\nabla$ is a constant sheaf.
What can we say here?

I would even be content to understand the simplified case of: $\mathcal{E}$ a line bundle and $\pi$ relative dimension 1 with normal crossing singularities.

Comment: I would guess that, at least in characteristic 0, $\mathcal{E}^{\nabla}$ is a vector bundle on $S$ which is trivialized by a finite etale covering $S' \rightarrow S$ (i.e. a finite vector bundle in the sense of Nori).

Comment: @JesseSilliman Thank you for the suggestion. Can you recommend a reference for that topic? Also, the characteristic is an important detail I neglected to mention.

Comment: @JesseSilliman I don't see why it should be trivialized. Can't we take the pullback of any vector bundle and use the standard connection on the fibers (since it's the trivial bundle on the fibers)? But the distinction may not be so relevant for this problem.

Comment: Probably you can check that this sheaf satisfies a relative form of flasqueness, where for $U \subset V$ open sets, if the image of $U$ and $V$ in $S$ is the same, then the restriction map is surjective. The point is to consider a section on $U$, which has a pole on some component of $V \setminus U$, and check that the derivative must have a pole of higher order to get a contradiction. Then that claim should suffice for vanishing of the higher direct image.

Comment: @WillSawin I think I should have said that I'm guessing that $\mathcal{E}^{\nabla}$ is a finite rank $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_S$-module on $X$ which becomes a "constant", i.e. pulled back from on $S$, after a finite etale covering $X' \rightarrow X$. This is not a Nori finite vector bundle anymore, though.

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you, good idea. Pardon my ignorance, but what do I need to make that work? $X$ normal, to use Weil divisors and valuation rings?

Comment: @JesseSilliman I'm unfamiliar with that type of object. Do you have any suggestions for how to prove something like that? And should that be finite rank $\pi^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S$-module?

Comment: I'm not sure what is needed exactly but normal sounds right.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal Yes, I meant $\pi^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S$, and you are right that some sort of hypothesis, such as normal, is necessary. If $S = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, this type of object is a sheaf whose analytification is a $\mathbb{C}$-local system on $X^{\mathrm{an}}$ with finite monodromy.